# Matlab - plot directly to .ps file

Tags: matlab

Currently I am trying to do something like:

```
h       =   figure( 1 );
subplot( 1, 2, 1);
plot( X, Y );
grid on;
xlabel( 'abc' );
ylabel( 'xyz' );
title( 'Nice' );        
legend( 'Awesome' )

handles     =   findall( 0, 'type', 'figure' );
createPDF( 'outputFileName', numel( handles ) );
```

So, the above would generate a .fig output on screen. The module createPDF has calls to convert the open figure to .ps file and change them to PDF. When I run this locally on my PC I see all the figures popping up and they are then converted to .PS and ultimately to PDF

However, I am working on running this on the server as a batch process where there is no screen and hence I assume there will be no .fig output either. How do I send these plots straight to the .PS file. The above code runs in for loop and generates 45 different figures.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The print function is what you're looking for!

```
print('-dpsc2','-append','YourPSFile'); %// The '-append' is used to create a single file in the loop instead of multiple files.
```

Whole code:

```
clear
clc

for k = 1:5

X = 1:10;
Y = rand(1,10);

h = figure('Visible','off');

plot( X, Y );
grid on;
xlabel( 'abc' );
ylabel( 'xyz' );
title( 'Nice' );        
legend( 'Awesome' )

print('-dpsc2','-append','YourPSFile'); %//Simply replace 'YourPSFile'with the name you want. Easy to implement in a for-loop with sprintf for instance.

end
```

Here is a screen shot of the pdf:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Benoit_11 I learned something from your code today. Can you please add a for loop cause right now I am creating 45 PDFs using your code. I just want 1 PDF output. And if possible add that command which you used to convert the PS to PDF.

Comment: Yep I edited the answer; you just need to add the 'append' input in the call to print and you're good to go.

Comment: What command do you use to convert PS to PDF. I am using something which my firm created and not a big fan of that.

Comment: Oh and I actually opened the ps file with Acrobat and it works perfectly. For a Matlab script you can check this submission from the file exchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19516-ps2pdf

Comment: Thanks Benoit_11. I will let you know whether it works on my nightly process setup which I believe is a server and runs some version of Linux.